# Are all linear regulators adjustable?

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

Some linear regulators are marketed as "adjustable", but all linear regulators create a specific voltage in relation to their ground pins. Since the ground pin voltage can be offset from the circuit ground, e.g. by using a Zener diode or a feedback voltage divider, can't we adjust *any* linear regulator this way?

Comment: They won't necessarily meet their specifications in that condition.

Comment: @Hearth how do they know?

Comment: @user253751 Over the many years, I've seen 7805's (for example) used as variable regulators. But if memory serves one main difference is that fixed regulators dump their necessary operating current into the ground pin whereas devices like the LM317 dump that current into the output pin, making the adjust-pin current more predictable and stable over their spec'd operation. But it's been a long time and I've not kept up, either. (I also suspect there tend to be more functional blocks inside a variable regulator, which can be considered 'a good thing' by some.)

Comment: The reliable answer is no.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can; but if the regulator's ground current changes significantly (or drops too low), the zener may not regulate as well as is needed and output accuracy will be affected.

In addition, the additional ground impedance (from the zener) may tend to create instability.

Some regulators may have difficulty starting up (into a load at 0 V) if the regulator's ground pin is *higher* than the output.

For simple regulators like LM7805, using a zener usually works.

Answer (score 12):

An adjustable regulator is one with an exposed feedback node so that the output voltage can be set by the designer using an external resistor divider.

Contrast this with a fixed regulator. A fixed regulator does not use an external voltage divider (it may have one internally) and does not have an exposed feedback node.

If you choose to redefine what "adjustable" means you may be able to say that all regulators are adjustable. But under the current meaning, many regulator have a fixed output voltage. Because the distinction between "adjustable" and "fixed" is useful, I believe the existing terminology is useful and should be preserved.

The technique of "floating" a regulator above ground is sometimes used, but that is quite separate from the issue of whether the regulator is fixed or adjustable.

You may be thinking of regulators such as the LM317. This is an unusual regulator. I believe its topology is atypical. I notice that the datasheet contains this:
[image]

Most regulators do NOT pass their bias or quiescent current to the output pin. They pass their quiescent current to the GND pin. So if you were to use the GND pin as the nexus of a voltage divider, the quiescent current would create an error in the voltage found there. And the quiescent current may be variable (I am not sure). So I don't think this is advisable for the average linear regulator.

I downloaded the datasheet from here:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf

Comment: Many "adjustable regulators" appear to be traditional regulators, but with ADJ written on the schematic where GND normally is, and official instructions to offset the ground (which is called ADJ)

Comment: Oh, you mean like the LM317? I don't think most modern regulators can be used that way. You wouldn't want the GND pin to be the nexus of a voltage divider because the quiescent current would throw off the voltage divider rule by injecting current at the divider node. I guess it would work OK with smaller value resistors that swamp the effect of the quiescent current.

Comment: @user253751 The LM317 is not typical of regulators. Be careful not to falsely generalize here. just because the components share the same name for 2/3 pins does not mean the 3rd pins is the same just with a different name. The LM317 works by maintaining a fixed voltage between the OUT and ADJ pin. Most other regulators function by maintaining a fixed voltage between the ADJ pin (which may be wired internally or run out to the user) and their ground pin. So from this description, obviously not the same thing but with a different pin name.

Comment: @DKNguyen do other regulators not maintain a fixed voltage between their OUT and GND pins?

Comment: @user253751 they do when used within the recommended operating conditions. But if you consider carefully, that is not what you are assuming, that Vout-GND is constant. You are also assuming that the lower leg of a divider from the GND pin to some lower reference voltage node has a constant drop. I don't think you can assume that.

Comment: @user253751 In my previous post when I refer to a voltage being maintained constant between two pins, I am referring to the reference voltage that the regulator actually uses, not the output voltage.

Answer (score 7):

Let's go back to where this [arose](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639212/psu-does-not-deliver-enough-voltage-for-a-lm317-what-are-my-options/639214?noredirect=1#comment1694617_639214) from! This is going to be a specification, kind of, of [mkeith's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/639983/64158), so that's the more general thing.

The circuit that caused the question was based on an adjustable version of an LDO, the AP2202-ADJ. It's datasheet schematic looks like this:

[image: Schematic from datasheet]

Now the question was whether we could not take the non-adjustable version and do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyqwS7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea is that the regulator strives to regulate the difference between GND and Vout to be a fixed voltage, so that through R1 a constant current must flow, and thus we get an "inverse voltage divider", because that same current flows through R2, and we thus can adjust to a higher output voltage, defined by the ratio of R1+R2 to R2. Nice! We get the absolute values of R1, R2 to play with, but their ratio is locked.

Small problem: This is a loaded voltage divider. The GND pin of the AP2202 carries the quiescent/operational current. The [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2202.pdf) tells us how much that might vary:

Between the minimum and maximum output current, there's a range of 95 to 1900 µA (2500 µA if considering the whole temperature range). It mainly depends on output load current (Table on page 15).

So, assuming we don't want that to affect our output voltage by more than 1% (this regulator guarantees 1 % accuracy, so we're making it twice as bad), so we need the current through R2 to be in the order of 100 times the current difference of ca. 1800 µA to make the additional current not change the output voltage significantly. That's a whopping 180 mA to get that output stable!

Sadly, this regulator is only specified up to 150 mA. So, that solution doesn't work.

Now, you bring up a Zener to replace R2, which of course is nice, because then the voltage becomes less dependent on the current. If we keep the current through R1 at say, four or ten times the ground pin current variation, the resulting 10% change in current through the Zener will not affect the voltage across the Zener diode much. So, that might work here. Small caveats:

- Zeners are excellent thermometers, more than they are constant voltage generators. Solution would be to replace with a temperature-compensated precision voltage reference. (The venerable TL431 comes to mind, most models can sink 20 mA or more.)
- Don't forget that this is a very simple regulator, with nothing but a pass transistor. That means it can pull the output voltage *up*, not *down*. The only thing that can pull the output voltage down is the actual load (and now our voltage divider) discharging the output capacitor. While it's but little, reducing the load current reduces ground current, which in turn reduces the voltage across the Zener, will make the regulator turn off the pass transistor, even if just a little, reducing the current. I don't have any information on the dynamics on that process, but this might lead to exacerbated voltage downswings one the load current drops. It's unlikely this leads to instability, but I'm pretty certain it will have interesting effects on the ability to absorb switching noise from a digital circuit supplied with this.

Answer (score 6):

It's not like they just changed the name of the pin. If you look at the internal schematics you'll see that the output node of the LM317 is pretty much what in an LM7805 would be the ground node. This is why the quiescent current goes through the output as others have pointed out.

When you put a resistor or zener in the ground path of a fixed regulator you aren't really 'adjusting' it, you're just adding an offset. If you measure from the ground pin to the output it will still be regulating at it's rated voltage (assuming it's getting enough current through the ground pin).

Comment: "you aren't really 'adjusting' it, you're just adding an offset" - what's the difference?

Comment: @user253751 The result may be the same, but you're not adjusting what a fixed linear regulator does. It's a fixed output voltage in relation to its GND reference. Adjustable regulators always feature some kind of feedback.

Comment: @Seir even the LM317?

Comment: @user253751 The ADJUST input is part of the feedback loop, as can be seen in _9.2 Typical Application_ of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf).

Comment: @Seir you can do the same thing with a ground pin on a "non-adjustable" regulator - hence the question.

Comment: @user253751 You can do what you think is the same thing, but it's not the same thing. It's like if you have a 12V bench supply, you could put a 9V battery in series and get 21V, but it's not the same as setting a variable supply to 21V. It will sort of work but it won't work as well as doing it the right way. When you start to draw current the battery/supply combination is going to act differently than the variable supply.. regulation won't be as good, current may be limited, there could be stability problems. There are plenty of adjustable regulators out there, why kluge something together?

Answer (score 5):

From reading your question and some comments, it appears you're getting confused by the terminology.

A fixed regulator IC is designed to operate in the configuration shown in its datasheet's typical circuit. To operate, it only relies on components shown in that circuit and/or specified in the datasheet text. Then it will meet the specifications of its datasheet. The IC and those components form the fixed regulator circuit.

An adjustable regulator is the same. But its datasheet will show and specify the components for its output adjustment. The IC and those components form the adjustable regulator circuit.

So you must separate the term for the component from the term for the circuit. Adding extra parts around a fixed regulator can make a new, adjustable regulator circuit.

But the IC hasn't stopped being a fixed regulator. It still adjusts its output current to maintain a fixed voltage between its GND and VOUT terminals (or equiv).

So forcing external conditions on a fixed regulator, using circuitry the IC designers did not expect or require, doesn't change what that part is.

A fixed resistor doesn't become 'adjustable' when there's a potentiometer in parallel with it. The fixed resistor becomes part of an adjustable resistance circuit with two components in.

Comment: LM317 is a 3-terminal IC advertised as an "adjustable regulator".  It still adjusts its output current to maintain a **fixed** voltage between its GND and VOUT terminals (or equiv). (that voltage being 1.25V)

Comment: @user253751, yes - that's what I've said. From what you've said throughout this question, I think you're locked onto a pov on words, and also want a longer discussion on it.

Comment: Your answer seems to me to imply that there is a distinction between fixed and adjustable regulator components, as well as between fixed and adjustable regulator circuits - but the component is exactly the same, and  the datasheet is the only difference? even though the datasheet isn't part of the component?

Answer (score 4):

Not comparing floating regulators (like lm317) with common fixed voltage regulators (like 78xx), lets compare the [ST](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ld1117.pdf) and [TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf) datasheets for the LM1117, which is offered with fixed and adjustable versions and has a basic topology more similar to the lm317.

TI diagram (fixed and adjustable are shown):

[image]

ST diagram (fixed - there is no access to the node between the feedback resistors):

[image]

The difference is clear: the feedback voltage divider is inside the package. So, it is not a simple difference of marking ADJ or not.

For **this** IC, you could add a resistor between the GND pin of the fixed version of the IC and the GND of your circuit to *only increase* the output voltage. Variations of the quiescent current (e.g. with temperature) will cause variations at the output voltage.

> LM317 is a 3-terminal IC advertised as an "adjustable regulator". It still adjusts its output current to maintain a fixed voltage between its GND and VOUT terminals (or equiv). (that voltage being 1.25V)

Yes, if you connect the ADJ pin to the GND of the circuit and load the output with a resistor which guarantees the minimum output current. What is not obvious at the first glance: if you use the voltage divider to adjust the output voltage above the 1.25V, you can't use resistors with large values, otherwise changes in quiescent current would represent large changes to the output voltage.

Regardless of the method used to raise the potential of the GND pin of the fixed version (resistor, Zener, shunt regulator), you are on your own to find out the effect of this modification to the stability of the control loop and drift of the output voltage.

[image]

Comment: To the OP: Note that if you add an input bypass capacitor from the IN pin to the GND pin of the 2nd circuit, then the responsiveness of this regulator would be degraded (PSRR, load response, etc). If you add the capacitor from IN to circuit ground with R3 in series with the GND pin, you are far outside of recommended operating conditions.